# How do I create a simple rounded rectangle button in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

How do I create a simple rounded rectangle button in libgdx without using images? The button should have a drop shadow and should handle pressed state. I want it to be programmatic to make it easy to change the color, style later, etc.

Comment: Can you be specific about what you mean by images? Everything that you can see on a screen is an "image". What are you specifically trying to avoid, and why?

Comment: @Tenfour04 If you were a programmer you'd know. Images refer to files like jpgs, pngs etc that you design in something like photoshop. Programmatically making a button or otherwise mean you just create shapes, text, borders, shadows etc to create a a button. That way you can easily alter it 'programmatically' with code, rather than having to go back into photoshop to redo it all and re-export.

Comment: @Hasan Image does not exclusively mean an image file. Libgdx has a class called Image. I’ve also seen people ask questions about images, but they actually mean the Texture or Pixmap classes specifically, which are images loaded to native or GPU memory respectively. I was trying to determine if this was an XY problem. Was it necessary to come by four years later and try to insult me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding of your question was how to create a rounded rectangle within the program without having to pre-generate any images outside of code.

I was in a similar situation a while back and I ended writing the function below which generates a `Pixmap` rounded rectangle based on the parameters (all units are in pixels). It also works with differing alpha values to allow for opacity (which is why there are two `Pixmap` objects used).

The resulting `Pixmap` can then easily be passed to a constructor of a `Texture` if you find that easier to render with.

```
public static Pixmap createRoundedRectangle(int width, int height, int cornerRadius, Color color) {

        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(width, height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        Pixmap ret = new Pixmap(width, height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);

        pixmap.setColor(color);

        pixmap.fillCircle(cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
        pixmap.fillCircle(width - cornerRadius - 1, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
        pixmap.fillCircle(cornerRadius, height - cornerRadius - 1, cornerRadius);
        pixmap.fillCircle(width - cornerRadius - 1, height - cornerRadius - 1, cornerRadius);

        pixmap.fillRectangle(cornerRadius, 0, width - cornerRadius * 2, height);
        pixmap.fillRectangle(0, cornerRadius, width, height - cornerRadius * 2);

        ret.setColor(color);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                if (pixmap.getPixel(x, y) != 0) ret.drawPixel(x, y);
            }
        }
        pixmap.dispose();

        return ret;
    }
```

Using this function it shouldn't be too difficult to make your own wrapper object (e.g. `RoundedRectangle`) which would re-draw the image every time one of the parameters was changed and needed to be rendered.

Comment: It does O(width * height) operations which is fairly fast (however not in your loop) but you don't need to re-render the image each frame, rather only when any value is changed.